# Google Chrome Redirecionando para HTTPS em localhost ou virtual host

Tags: apache, http, google-chrome, https, virtualhost

Bom dia a todos.

Recentemente, não sei se foi alguma atualização do google, o navegador deles passou a fazer uma redirecionamento estranho.

Tenho servidor apache e quando entro em uma url configurada no localhost, mesmo que ela seja virtual como por exemplo www.equipe.com, que aponta para o 127.0.0.1, ele não acessa de forma alguma, até mesmo em minha residência.

Ele falha por alguma configuração proxy e vai para o mesmo link que coloco, porém forçando o HTTPS ao invés de HTTP.

Alguém sabe me dizer o que pode ser ou se já passou por isso?
(OBS: Falha apenas no navegador google, os demais estão normais)

Comment: Muito estranho isso, dá uma olhada no > chrome://flags dele para vê se encontra alguma coisa, estava com um problema de carregamento de plugins no meu, tomei uma atitude de resetar ele por lá, solucionou o meu caso.

Comment: OK, Vou tentar.

Answer (score 1):

O Chrome implementa o HTTS - HTTP Strict Transport Security - uma política que força os browsers a interagir com websites apenas usando o protocolo HTTPS de forma a garantir uma melhor segurança.

O HTTS funciona por omissão para qualquer nome de domínio e como para o browser está a tentar ligar-se a `www.empresa.com` e não `localhost` ele pensa que se está a ligar a um servidor remoto em vez de se estar a ligar a si mesmo e, como tal, força o HTTPS.

Tem duas opções:

1. Trocar a sua entrada local de `empresa.com` para `empresa.localhost` para explicitar que está a trabalhar localmente;
2. Acrescentar uma excepção para o domínio `empresa.com`nas definições internas do Chrome - o que **não** recomendo porque quando se estiver a ligar ao servidor de produção do seu domínimo `empresa.com`ele vai continuar a ignorar o HTTS e vai criar ligações inseguras por omissão com os recursos da sua empresa, **o que nunca é bom**.

---

> Pode consultar uma explicação mais detalhada sobre o assunto em [O que
>   significa o erro "A sua conexão não é privada. Este site usa HSTS" e
>   como o corrigir?](https://techglimpse.com/chrome-https-website-hsts-failed/) *(em Inglês)*